# Open a .sqlite3 file in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

Are there any javascript libraries out there to open a file `somefile.sqlite3` in javascript and then perform a predictable set of SQL queries on it?

Comment: When you say "javascript" do you mean in a browser, or using [nodejs](http://nodejs.org)?

Comment: in a browser, ideally I'd like to write a static page that did this

Comment: I wouldn't be running arbitrary SQL against a server, I would be performing queries on a copy of a .sqlite3 file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any libraries that could open, much less query a sqlite3 file from a browser. Binary data support in the browser is lackluster, even if you jumped through the necessary hoops to open the file at all.